# Mockserver: callback once request is received

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, mockserver

I'm using Mockserver to test an HTTP service that produces side-effects asynchronously. Let's say for example, I'm testing `ServiceA` that exposes an HTTP API method at `/api/status/{id}`. Separately from returning the status result to the caller of the API, `ServiceA` kicks off an async analysis that calls `ServiceB` if some conditions are met. Let's say this takes from a few milliseconds to a few seconds for this async process to complete.

Currently, my mockserver code looks something like this:

```
Long waitTimeoutSeconds = 5L;
Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
HttpRequest[] asyncRequestsRetrieved = null;

while (start + (waitTimeoutSeconds * 1000L) < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    asyncRequestsRetrieved = mockServer.retrieveRecordedRequests(HttpRequest.request().withPath("/service/b/path"));
    if (asyncRequestsRetrieved != null && asyncRequestsRetrieved.size > 0) {
        break;
    }
    Thread.sleep(50L);
}

assertNotNull(asyncRequestsRetrieved);
assertTrue(asyncRequestsRetrieved!!.size > 0);
```

Does Mockserver expose a pattern to take an action (say, notify a listener) when a request is received at a given endpoint, or is polling my only option?

Comment: https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility Id recommend using awaitility, it has some expanded options for polling and waiting for verifications including ignoring certain exception. Will save you writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending request to `ServiceB` in async then you will get some response back, in that case polling is the only option.
I assume your `ServiceB` has 2 endpoints one for creating a job and another to check the status of the job, and if it is ready then get the result.